# java spring + login endpoint not getting called even after Previously Authenticated and Authorization successful

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, jwt, jersey

I am implementing jwt with spring security 4.1.0.Release and spring framework 4.3.14.Release with jersey implementation for REST.
my filter is getting called and in the logs I am getting previously authenticated and Authorization successfull, yet my /login endpoint is not getting called where I am generating the token and will pass it back to caller.

```
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtFilter'
Bearer String not found in token
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3edc2235, returned: 1
DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@6649e5d0
```

Controller code:

```
package com.dtaf;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtController {
   @Autowired
   private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
   @Autowired
   private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
   @Autowired
   private TokenManager tokenManager;
   @POST
   @Path("/login")
   public ResponseEntity createToken(@RequestBody JwtRequestModel
   request) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("In login method");

      try {
         authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(),
            request.getPassword())
         );
      } catch (DisabledException e) {
         throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
      } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
         throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
      }
      final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
      final String jwtToken = tokenManager.generateJwtToken(userDetails);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponseModel(jwtToken));
   }
   
   
}
```

websecurity code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dtaf"})
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Autowired
       private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
       @Autowired
       private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
       @Autowired
       private JwtFilter filter;
       @Bean
       public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
          return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
       }
       @Override
       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
       }
       @Bean
       @Override
       public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws
       Exception {
          return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
          .and()
          .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
          http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
       }
}
```

jwtfilter

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   @Autowired
   private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
   @Autowired
   private TokenManager tokenManager;
   @Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      
      String tokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      String username = null;
      String token = null;
      if (tokenHeader != null && tokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
         token = tokenHeader.substring(7);
         try {
            username = tokenManager.getUsernameFromToken(token);
         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
         } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
         }
      } else {
         System.out.println("Bearer String not found in token");
      }
      if (null != username &&SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
          
          System.out.println("username "+ username);
         UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
         if (tokenManager.validateJwtToken(token, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null,
            userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authenticationToken.setDetails(new
            WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
         }
      }
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Data Services</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/config/BeanLocations.xml,classpath:spring/config/Spring-Quartz.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.dtaf.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <!-- Spring Security -->  
  <filter>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
  </filter>  
  <filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dtaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>taf</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>af</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.14.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!--These are needed for Jersey -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- REST specific -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-adhoc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamicreports-googlecharts</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency> 
         <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId> 
         <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId> 
         <version>0.9.1</version> 
      </dependency>
      
      

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>request-generate-dataaggregator</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/request/dataaggregator/</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.dtaf.model.request.dataaggregator</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>response-generate-dataaggregator</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/response/dataaggregator/</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.dtaf.model.response.dataaggregator</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>request-generate-scriptaggregator</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/request/scriptaggregator/</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.dtaf.model.request.scriptaggregator</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>response-generate-scriptaggregator</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/response/scriptaggregator/</schemaDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.dtaf.model.response.scriptaggregator</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
            <!--Change the execution phase as install in local environment -->
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.1</version> <configuration> <url>http://localhost:9080/manager/text</url> 
                <username>manager</username> <password>manager</password> <path>/cavs</path> 
                <update>true</update> </configuration> <executions> <execution> <id>tomcat-deploy</id> 
                <phase> install</phase> <goals> <goal>deploy</goal> </goals> </execution> 
                </executions> </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I did tried the same exact steps with new spring boot project and everything is working fine.
It seems some setting needs to be done while doing the same in spring framework.

Comment: @SahilMehta Change the path of your endpoint, `/login` is used by Spring Security.

Comment: @dur : changed the endpoint name to "Pool" , still the same situation, endpoint is not getting invoked.